# Counting integers $n \leq x$ such that $rad(n)=r$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, algorithms

Let $r$ be the largest square-free integer that divides $n$. Then $$r = \operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p$$ $r$ is called the "radical" of $n$, or the square-free kernel. Have also seen the term "core". For a given square-free $r$ and integer $x$, my question is how many integers $n\leq x$ exist such that $\operatorname{rad}(n) = r$. For example with $r=15$, and $x=100$, then $15,45,75$ are the only $3$ such integers. I haven't found any formula or algorithm in the literature that seems useful here, for generic $r$ and $x$.

Comment: This is a slight generalization of counting smooth numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number). There's an asymptotic count on Wikipedia which probably adapts to this case. Are you looking for an exact count?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, looking for an exact count

Comment: This is hard, as far as I know. You can see this paper by Granville: https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/msrire.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In general I think this is hard. But, you can look at the following algorithm:

Factor $r$ into primes as: $r = p_1 \cdots p_k$.
Note that $\text{rad}(n) = r \iff n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$ for some integers $a_i$.

To determine the number of $(a_1, \dots , a_k)$ such that $n \leq x$ we can count the solutions $(a_1, \dots , a_k)$ of $a_1 \log(p_1) + \dots + a_k \log(p_k) \leq \log(x)$.

If $r$ is prime, then the number of solutions can be determined very efficiently. If $r$ is not prime ($k > 1$), then this is more difficult.

You can do it somewhat efficiently by looping over the $a_i$ and and by stopping early if the sum $a_1 \log(p_1) + \dots + a_k \log(p_k)$ exceeds $\log(x)$.

One other way is to note that the vectors $v_i = (0, \dots , \log(a_i), \dots , 0)$ for $1 \leq 1 \leq k$ span a lattice.
We are asking for the number of lattice points inside the convex set defined by $a_1 \log(p_1) + \dots + a_k \log(p_k) \leq \log(x)$.
Perhaps a more efficient algorithm can be found that way.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat efficient algorithm can be devised based on [Enumerating and counting smooth integers](https://cr.yp.to/papers/epsi-19950518-retypeset20220326.pdf) by D.J.Bernstein.

We'll count numbers, such that $\text{rad}(n) \mid r$, because
$$ \#\{ n \mid n \leqslant x, \text{rad}(n) = r \} = \#\{ n \mid n \leqslant \frac{x}{r}, \text{rad}(n) \mid r \}$$

Let $r = p_1p_2\cdots p_k$.
Following paper notation, let $P(x, S)$ -- be the set of numbers, which are products of distinct elements of $S$ and are $\leqslant x$, and $\Psi(x, S) = \lvert P(x, S) \rvert$.

Obviously you are looking for a $\Psi(x, S)$, where $S = \{ p_i^{2^t} \mid t \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap [1, x]$.

You can enumerate $P(x, S)$ directly by Algorithm 2 in linear of resulting set time, but it can be big. You can also use Algorithm 3, but I'd suggest different approach for counting $\Psi(x, S)$ in $O(\Psi(\sqrt{x}, S))$ time.

First, enumerate $P(\sqrt{x}, S)$ in $O(\Psi(\sqrt{x}, S))$ time using Algorithm 2.

Then introduce $f(n, i)$ -- numbers which have radical $p_1\cdots p_i$ and are less or equal than $n$. One may see obvious recurrence $f(n, i) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty f\left(\Bigl\lfloor \frac{n}{p_i^t} \Bigr\rfloor, i - 1\right)$.

Because $\lfloor \frac{\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \rfloor}{b} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}{ab} \rfloor$, the only states we're needed to compute are form $\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \rfloor$. But if $\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \rfloor < \sqrt{x}$ we can compute $f$ directly without recurrence, since all numbers before $\sqrt{x}$ are already enumerated. Also each state $\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \rfloor > \sqrt{x}$ corresponds to a number $a < \sqrt{x}$ with $\text{rad}(a) \mid r$, so there are $O(\Psi(\sqrt{x}, S))$ such states.

That is, you can just compute $\Psi(x, S) = f\left(\lfloor x \rfloor, k\right)$ using recurrence and preenumerated numbers in desired time, maybe with some logarithmic factors arising from inaccurate explanation.

---

Algorithm 3 from paper pretends to work in $O(\sqrt{\Psi(x, S)})$, but it requires proper partition of $S$, which existence for arbitrary $r$ is hard question. From lattice arguments $\Psi(x, S) \sim \frac{1}{k!} \prod\limits_{i = 1}^{k} \frac{\log x}{\log p}$ for fixed $r$ and $x \to \infty$, so generally $\sqrt{\Psi(x, S)} \ll \Psi(\sqrt{x}, S)$ as $x \to \infty$.

But actually proving this complexity is difficult and estimate for $\Psi(x, S)$ is very rough(try it yourself for $x \approx 10^{18}$ for some $r$), so in practice my approach should be better.